# Feeds XPath parser - how to map to complex content types (eg to field collection field)

Tags: 7, entities, feeds

I've managed to import nodes of content using the XPath imporer, but where there are deeper levels of data structures, there seems to be no way to map data to a node.

I would have liked to have created these content types using the Field Collection module, 
but there's no support for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Field collection feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_feeds) module which provides [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) integration for [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.

You can read [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1831004) how to import field collection using feeds.